# Does this elementary geometry theorem about trapezoids and cyclic quadrilaterals have a name?

Tags: geometry, reference-request

While solving a problem (of a still ongoing kind of contest - so perhaps you should refrain from posting *proofs* of the theorem!), I noticed that an intermediate step can readily be adapted to produce a sufficiently nice result, namely:

> **Theorem.** Let $ABCD$ be a trapezoid with $AB\parallel CD$. Let $C'$ and $D'$ be the orthogonal projections of $C$ and $D$ to $BD$ and $AC$, respectively. Then $ABC'D'$ is cyclic.

This is not too difficult to show with elementary geometry, so I would not be surprised if it already appears in good ole Euklid's *Elements*. However, I could not find anything close enough. Does anyone recognize this as well-known (and named after someone)?

I will of course keep that part of my submission as is, but it still nags me and I am curious whether I could have reduced my solution from almost a page to about half a page by quoting a well-known(??) theorem ...

Answer (score 0):

Note that $CDD’C’$ (or $CDC’D’$) is cyclic with $CD$ the diameter. If one generalizes this to any circle through $C,D$ with $C’,D’$ the additional intersections of the circle with the lines $BD$ and $AC$, then the result follows directly from properties of circles, namely Book III.21, III.22 of Elements and angles regarding a transversal to two parallel lines.

Alternatively, the above generalization is a special case of the [Three Conics Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ThreeConicsTheorem.html#:%7E:text=%2C%20then%20the%20six%20points%20lie,intersect%20at%20three%20collinear%20points.) (see the second picture of the link by replacing $E$ with the degenerate conic that is the locus of two intersecting lines $AC$ and $BD$).